# Basic Value Compare Evaluation not working in Lua

Tags: lua, evaluation

I am trying to compare 2 values and they appear to be equal but are still being evaluated as different.

What am i doing wrong? Any ideas? I added tonumber() just to be sure I wasn't converting one to a string somewhere.

```
--Check to see if the current health and the target health differ
if tonumber( characterStatus.current[ statusColor .. "Health" ] ) ~= tonumber( characterStatus.target[ statusColor .. "Health" ] ) then
    --Current and Target Heath amounts differ

    if statusColor == "monster" then print( "\nMonster Amounts Differ  ~~~~~~~~~~=" .. characterStatus.current[ statusColor .. "Health" ] .. characterStatus.target[ statusColor .. "Health" ] .. "=" ) end
end
```

The output is "Monster Amounts Differ  ~~~~~~~~~~=99="

Comment: Floating point value for one of the numbers being rounded away in display but not in tonumber perhaps? What does `print(characterStatus.current[ statusColor .. "Health" ] % 1)` say versus `print(characterStatus.target[ statusColor .. "Health" ] % 1)`?

Comment: Somthing is going on... The output for that is: 7.1054253546001e-015, 0. I use math.ceil on some of my calcs with this number. Would that have anything to so with it? And better yet, How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Lua numbers are just doubles, and one doesn't simply test arbitrary doubles for equality.

http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/

Answer (score -1):

Cleanup your code so less risk of typos, and print the difference between the two values:

```
local scCurrent = tonumber(characterStatus.current[ statusColor .. "Health" ])
local scTarget  = tonumber(characterStatus.target [ statusColor .. "Health" ])
if scCurrent ~= scTarget then
    local scDiff = scCurrent - scTarget
    if statusColor == "monster" then 
        print( scCurrent, scTarget, scDiff) 
    end
end
```

You will see what the difference is between the two values. You may need to use string.format to format the output.

Comment: Whoever -1'd please comment why, otherwise how can I improve the answer?